# Генератор случайных чисел std::mt19937 из <random> всегда выдает одно и то же число

Tags: c++, c++11

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно создать функцию, которая возвращала бы случайное число. Чуть ниже можно посмотреть, как я это пробовал реализовать. Ошибок нет, число есть, проблема в том, что число это всегда одно и тоже. Ну и как вы уже вероятно догадались, вопрос в том, как мне исправить данную ситуацию? Желательно с примером.

```
int TestClass::returnRandom(int max){
std::random_device randD;
std::mt19937 randMT(randD());
std::uniform_int_distribution <int> range(0, max);
return range(randMT);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Проблема в том, что `randMT` каждый раз создается заново.

`std::mt19937` - это генератор псевдослучайных чисел, для получения последовательности чисел его надо создать один раз, и потом использовать его вместе с каким-то случайным распределением чтобы получать случайные числа.

По этому его надо сделать членом класса:

```
class TestClass {
public:
  TestClass() {
    std::random_device device;
    random_generator_.seed(device());
  }

  int returnRandom(int max) {
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> range(0, max);
    return range(random_generator_);
  }

private:
  std::mt19937 random_generator_;
};
```

Если класс создается много раз и часто, то есть смысл создавать объект `std::random_device` не в конструкторе, а где-то еще, т.к. его создание тоже может быть медленной операцией.

Также объект `std::mt19937` можно инициализировать текущим временем. Однако это слабый источник энтропии, потому что у текущего времени очень мало случайных бит.

```
auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
random_generator_.seed(now.time_since_epoch().count());
```

Comment: Спасибо за Ваш ответ,  честно говоря даже не знаю, какой из ответов выбрать.  Пример предложенный Max ZS, более компактный, однако, он использует время в качестве семени, в свою очередь Ваш ответ, с random_device больше соответствует схемам использования  mt19937 из которых я изначально исходил.
Интересно, существует ли практическая разница между этими подходами? Хотя наверно это тема для отдельного вопроса.....
Пожалуй, оставлю первый вариант выбранным хотя бы потому, что в противном случае мне будет неудобно перед товарищем Max ZS, за свою переменчивость. Уж простите за подобные сантименты.

Comment: @Jonathan_Cage здесь не может быть места неудобству перед кем-либо. Ведь смысл ресурса в том, чтобы потом другие могли воспользоваться правильными ответами. Поэтому, если считаете, что более правильным ответом на Ваш вопрос является ответ именно Abyx, то отмечайте его. Со своей стороны я могу добавить лишь то, что уже неоднократно писал на данном ресурсе об использовании `std::random_device` - не на всех сборках он работает. Поэтому решать Вам, использовать его или нет.

Comment: @Abyx Под Windows в [mingw-w64 он не работает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/825386), а в VisualStudio работает.