# Не работает random_device

Tags: c++, linux, windows, mingw, wine

Имеется следующий код:

```
    std::random_device rd;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, N_BRICK_KIND - 1);
    figure = static_cast<BrickType>(dist(rd));
```

На линуксе работает без проблем, но вот когда компилирую под винду (кросскомпиляция с помощью `mingw`) и запускаю под wine, то этот код приводит к одним и тем же результатам, всегда. При этом результат можно изменить только если перекомпилировать прогу. Заменил этот код на си-шный `srand - rand` - работает, но почему не работает код выше?

Comment: Добавлю именно как комментарий - не рекомендуется использовать `random_device` для генерации самих случайных чисел - а только для инициализации другого генератора.

Comment: @Harry я пробовал с mt19937 - но результат тоже... Кстати, а почему не рекомендуется?

Comment: Да точно не помню, кажется, у Гантерота в "Оптимизации программ на С++" писалось (точно источник не помню, впрочем...) - что он существенно более медленный, не везде реализован и вообще может выбросить исключение. Но кто мешает прибегнуть к старому способу - взять тот же mt19937 и инициализировать значением time(0)? :)

Comment: Тикет в багтрекере mingw-w64: [#338 std::random_device not working properly](https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw-w64/bugs/338/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот похожий вопрос из [английского SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880654/why-do-i-get-the-same-sequence-for-every-run-with-stdrandom-device-with-mingw). Если кратко, то насколько я понимаю, в MingW для Windows еще не реализован `random_device`. Рекомендуют использовать версию из boost.